# Google Script Google URL API Invalid Value (line 5, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-url-shortener

I'm running the below script that will read from google sheets but is failing with the error"

```
Invalid Value (line 5, file "Code")

function GetShortUrlClicks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get(data ,{projection:'FULL'}).getAnalytics();
    var clicks = analytics.getAllTime();
    Logger.log(clicks)
  }
}
```

However, if I run the same script with a URL in place of data the script runs and I get the proper data back working the Google URL API that equals to the amount of cells I have in the Google Sheet.

```
function GetShortUrlClicks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get('google.com',{projection:'FULL'}).getAnalytics();
    var clicks = analytics.getAllTime();
    Logger.log(clicks)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming the data variable is not getting passed properly.

Comment: you areusing `data`here (the whole table) instead of `data[i][0]`

Comment: @Harold so should it be `var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get(data[i][0] ,{projection:'FULL'}).getAnalytics();`

Comment: yes if the data are on your first column if not change for the number of the column (count start at 0) . you should also put on the previous line 'if(data[i][0] == ""){continue;}' to skip empty rows. You logged 'clicks' but you should also log 'data[i][0]' to be sure of what you are giving to your UrlShortener?

Comment: @Harold that change didn't work.  I get the same error.  Looking at the debugger I'm not getting the array click data.  I'm just getting the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

Update with the below.

```
 var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get(data[i],{projection:'FULL'}).getAnalytics();
```